# UITableView Delegate Not Found In Documentation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I couldn't find this method in the UITableView delegate documentation....can you tell me where I would look for the documentation for this method?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a method of `UITableViewDataSource` (since it invokes a modification of your data).